# keep position of divs if one is not displayed

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to use ngIf for displaying a div in my code.
My problem is that when "code" is null, my div won't be displayed(as expected), but the code below it will not stay in its place,it will come up.
How can I keep in place 'fees' when 'codes' is not displayed?

[image]

[image]

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="col-6">
    <div *ngIf="code">
        <small><b>Codes: </b></small><br>
           {{code}}<br>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <small><b>Fees</b></small><br>
      {{fees}}$
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that could help would be wrapping your ngIf div inside another div with the properties you have in the ngIf div, e.g.:

```
<div> <== this one will take the style properties from its child.
    <div *ngIf="code"> <== here you remove the styles and let it be just a wrapper.
        <small><b>Codes: </b></small><br>
           {{code}}<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

The property could be a "height" for instance, so it will preserve the height no matter if the code inside exists or does not.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `*ngIf` use `[hidden]`.

Difference:

`*ngIf="false"`, element is removed from DOM
`[hidden]="true"`, sets the display to none in css